# Returning a Dictionary from a gouped query

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, group-by

I have a table in my SQL Anywhere 12.0.1 database:

```
CREATE TABLE Entries (
    ListId        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    . . .
);
```

I need to query the table to get the number of rows in the table that have the same ListID.  In SQL:

```
SELECT ListID, COUNT(*)
FROM Entries
GROUP BY ListId;
```

I want to execute this query using Entity Framework 4.x, and I want to return the results as a `Dictionary<Guid, long>`.  Something like this:

```
public Dictionary<Guid, long> GetRowCounts( MyEntities context ) {
    Dictionary<Guid, long> result = null;
    try {
        result = ( from entry in Entries
                   group entry by entry.ListId into listGroup
                   select listGroup ).ToDictionary( grp => grp.Key, ???? );

    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        . . .
    }
    return result;
}
```

Remember, I want the count of rows that have each unique ListId returned.  What do I put in place of the "????"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, look at what you wrote:

> Remember, I want the **count** of rows

(emphasis mine). So you need:

```
ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count())
```

Personally I'd write the method like this though:

```
public Dictionary<Guid, int> GetRowCounts(MyEntities context) {
    return context.Entries
                  .GroupBy(entry => entry.ListId)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
}
```

... or if you still want it to be a `Dictionary<Guid, long>`, use `g => g.LongCount()`, or just cast:

```
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => (long) g.Count())
```

You almost *certainly* don't want the try/catch block there, and returning directly is a lot simpler. Likewise, unless you're writing a moderately complex query, there's really no benefit in using a query expression. Learn to use the extension methods directly too, so that for each query you can write the simplest possible code.

Comment: I tried that; it won't compile. Now that I look at it, the error is that you can't convert a `Dictionary<Guid, int>` into a `Dictionary<Guid, long>`.  Guess I'll change the type of the Dictionary's value to an int.  Thanks.

Comment: @TonyVitabile: Either that, or use `LongCount()`. I'll edit my answer.